# How To use Custom Control in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

how to use custom control in Jqgrid for Field. example in add/edit popup  I have a date field and i Want use persionDatePiker, How do these settings?

Thanks all,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yoou need to set `edittype` to  `custom` and provide `custom_element` and `custom_value` functions. Example from documentation:

```
<script>
function myelem (value, options) {
  var el = document.createElement("input");
  el.type="text";
  el.value = value;
  return el;
}

function myvalue(elem, operation, value) {
    if(operation === 'get') {
       return $(elem).find("input").val();
    } else if(operation === 'set') {
       $('input',elem).val(value);
    }
}

jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
   colModel: [ 
      {
        name:'price',
        editable:true, 
        edittype:'custom', 
        editoptions:{
            custom_element: myelem, 
            custom_value:myvalue
        }
     },
   //...
   ]
});
</script>
```

But in order to integrate e.g. [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) I used the following code:

```
{
    name:'startTime',
    label: 'Start time',
    editable: true,
    editoptions: {
        dataInit: function (e) {
            $(e).datetimepicker({});
        }
    }
}
```

See [Common Editing Properties](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules) for details.

Comment: ,I write a control using jQuery for PersianToolpack, how do I use it? i Use asp.net. thanks